# operaciones entre columnas de consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta sql server

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, u.group_identifier,  
  u.identifier, u.user_profile, u.user_scheduler,   
 e.cargo,  t.description, t.start_hour, t.end_hour, t.break_minutes,  
 (SELECT sum(venta) as venta FROM venta as v 
       WHERE v.id_calendario = (SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)) 
         AND v.id_almacen = 47  AND tipo = 'PPTO' ) as meta_diaria, 
 (SELECT (DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) ) - (break_minutes/60) ) as horas 

FROM usuarios as u  
     INNER JOIN planificacion as p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
     INNER JOIN turnos as t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
     INNER JOIN empleado as e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '')  =  u.identifier 

WHERE (p.begins >= 20190701000000 AND p.begins <= 20190705000000) 
     AND u.group_identifier = '125' AND u.enabled = 1 
ORDER BY begins, identifier ASC
```

Lo que resulta en las columnas en verde y necesito calcular las columnas en rojo, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer en ésta misma query? Tomando en cuenta que:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

1. Total_horas_dia es la suma de las horas para todos los cargos que si trabajan ése día excepto JEFE DE TIENDA.
2. Fracción_meta es la división de la meta_diaria entre las horas resultantes en 1.

Comment: Quieres decir que resulta en las columnas en rojo y necesitas calcular las columnas en verde?

Comment: si, necesito todas las columnas, tanto las que estánen rojo como las que están en verde. Ya tengo las que están en rojo @LuisCazares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dándole un poco de formato a tu consulta y moviendo la subconsulta a una cláusula APPLY, sólo hace falta hacer una suma condicional utilizando OVER para convertir una función de agregado en una función de ventana.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9) as begins, 
    u.group_identifier,  
    u.identifier, 
    u.user_profile, 
    u.user_scheduler,   
    e.cargo,  
    t.description, 
    t.start_hour, 
    t.end_hour, 
    t.break_minutes,  
    md.meta_diaria,
    DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60)  as horas,
    SUM( CASE WHEN u.user_profile <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)) AS total_horas_dia,
    md.meta_diaria / SUM( CASE WHEN u.user_profile <> 'JEFE(A) DE TIENDA' THEN DATEDIFF(hour, start_hour, end_hour ) - (break_minutes/60) END) OVER(PARTITION BY SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)) AS fraccion_meta
FROM       usuarios      AS u  
INNER JOIN planificacion AS p ON u.identifier = p.identifier 
INNER JOIN turnos        AS t ON t.id_shift = p.hashed_shift_id 
INNER JOIN empleado      AS e ON REPLACE(e.cod_empleado, '-', '')  =  u.identifier 
OUTER APPLY (SELECT sum(venta) as meta_diaria 
        FROM venta as v 
        WHERE v.id_calendario = SUBSTRING (p.begins, 0, 9)
         AND v.id_almacen = 47  
         AND tipo = 'PPTO' ) AS md
WHERE p.begins >= 20190701000000 AND p.begins <= 20190705000000
AND u.group_identifier = '125' 
AND u.enabled = 1 
ORDER BY begins, identifier ASC;
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias  @LuisCazares